# Sum of inverse functions equal to the inverse of the sum of functions

Tags: functions, inverse

I am interested in functions $f$ that for a given sequence of real positive numbers $\{a_i\}$ hold the equality
$$\sum_i a_i f^{-1}\left(f(x_i)\right) = f^{-1}\left(\sum_i a_i f(x_i)\right)$$.

Clearly, $f(x)=x$ is one such example, but are there any others?
What about the special case $a_i =1 \forall i$?

Comment: Any linear invertible function will satisfy this property

Comment: Your equation simplifies to $\sum_i a_i x_i = f^{-1}\Big(\sum_i a_i f(x_i)\Big)$, right?

Comment: Is the sequence $\{a_i\}$ finite or infinite? If it is an infinite sequence, do you require the series to converge?

Comment: @OlivierRoche, Yes to the first question. As to the second, let's say infinite and that the sequence converges. I am specifically interested in whether or not there is a non-linear solution to the equation.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Is there a non-invertible linear function other than a constant?

Comment: @user3350919 Implicitely, $f$ must be invertible, since you use its reciprocal $f^{-1}$.

Comment: By the way, what are the $x_i$s? Did you mean that the equality must hold for all $(x_i)_{i\in I}$?

Comment: @OlivierRoche I was referring to Dhanvi answer where he said the function should be linear and invertible and wondered whether linear doesn't imply invertible (except for $f(x)=c$). Anyway, I will share how I originally came to wonder about this: I was looking on a PDF $f_X(x)$ and wondered about the cases when $E_X\{g(x)\}=g(E\{x\})$. Specifically, I wonder if this must imply that $g(x)$ is linear.

Comment: @user3350919 I'm lost here, what's $X$, what's $f_X$, what's $E_X$?

Comment: @OlivierRoche Sorry. $X$ is a random variable with PDF $f_X(x)$, and $E_X$ is the expectation operator according to the PDF $f_X(x)$